# error: Failed dependencies: /usr/lib/libc.so is needed by devtoolset-8-systemtap-testsuite-3.3-1.el7.x86_64

Tags: gcc, centos7, glibc, libc, devtoolset

I was trying to install devtoolset-8 in my slave node with no active internet connection running centos7. I am using all .rpm packages required as dependencies.

During installation through rpm -ivh * I get

```
[root@node3 install]# rpm -ivh *
warning: dejagnu-1.5.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
warning: devtoolset-8-8.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID f2ee9d55: NOKEY
warning: package devtoolset-8-8.0-2.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-8.1-1.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-build-8.0-2.bs1.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-build-8.0-2.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-build-8.0-2.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-build-8.1-1.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-8.1-1.el7.x86_64 was already added, skipping devtoolset-8-dockerfiles-8.0-2.bs1.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-8.1-1.el7.x86_64 was already added, skipping devtoolset-8-dockerfiles-8.0-2.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-perftools-8.0-2.bs1.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-perftools-8.0-2.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-perftools-8.0-2.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-perftools-8.1-1.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-runtime-8.0-2.bs1.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-runtime-8.0-2.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-runtime-8.0-2.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-runtime-8.1-1.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-toolchain-8.0-2.bs1.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-toolchain-8.0-2.el7.x86_64
warning: package devtoolset-8-toolchain-8.0-2.el7.x86_64 was already added, replacing with devtoolset-8-toolchain-8.1-1.el7.x86_64
error: Failed dependencies:
        /usr/lib/libc.so is needed by devtoolset-8-systemtap-testsuite-3.3-1.el7.x86_64
```

output of locate libc.so is as follows

```
[root@node3 install]# locate libc.so
/opt/intel/advisor_2018.1.1.535164/lib32/pinruntime/glibc/libc.so.6
/opt/intel/advisor_2018.1.1.535164/lib64/pinruntime/glibc/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/libc.so
/usr/lib/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/lib64/libc.so
/usr/lib64/libc.so
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6
[root@node3 install]#
```

The details of lib and lib64 libc.so is as follows

```
[root@node3 install]# ll /usr/lib64/libc.so*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 253 Nov  5  2016 /usr/lib64/libc.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  12 Oct 13  2017 /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.17.so
[root@node3 install]# ll /usr/lib/libc.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec 16 16:45 /usr/lib/libc.so -> /usr/lib64/libc.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Dec 16 17:35 /usr/lib/libc.so.6 -> /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
```

I need updated gcc , and only way is I found it through devtoolset. please suggest any possible solution that does not require active internet connectivity.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to install `devtoolset-8-systemtap-testsuite`? This package is only needed for testing Systemtap (not even *using* Systemtap).

Apart from that, these symbolic links are very unusual and suggest that something is broken with the system:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec 16 16:45 /usr/lib/libc.so -> /usr/lib64/libc.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Dec 16 17:35 /usr/lib/libc.so.6 -> /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
```

`/usr/lib/libc.so` should be a linker script for linking with the 32-bit version of glibc. It is installed by the `glibc-devel.i686` package.